# CharSet gets reset

Tags: delphi, character-encoding, indy10

I init my socket using the following code

```
  Socket:=TmyidHTTP.Create(NIL);
  IOHandler:=TIdIOHandlerStack.Create(Socket);

  Socket.HandleRedirects:=true;
  Socket.AllowCookies:=FALSE;
  Socket.ProtocolVersion:=pv1_1;
  Socket.HTTPOptions:=Socket.HTTPOptions+[hoKeepOrigProtocol]+[hoNoProtocolErrorException]+[hoWantProtocolErrorContent];
  Socket.Request.CustomHeaders.FoldLines:=FALSE;
  Socket.Request.CharSet:='utf-8';
  Socket.Request.ContentType:='text/txt';
  Socket.Request.Accept:='*/*';
  // Socket.ReuseSocket:=rsTrue;
  Socket.Request.Connection:='keep-alive';
```

(TmyidHTTP only publishes the protected `DoRequest`)

but when I look into the protocol I see the following header: `charset=ISO-8859-1`.

only if I specify the `Socket.Request.CharSet:='utf-8';` *again* before a post, then it works...

any ideas what is resetting the CharSet??

Comment: What do you mean by "resetting"?  You're creating a new client and have observed the default Latin1 char-set.  Here you're setting it to `utf-8` and observing that it changes as expected.  Where is the "resetting" part?  I think this needs a [mcve].

Comment: I thought I had explained it well, obviously not: I create the the socket like described with setting the charset to utf8. When posting stuff I see a different encoding in the header. It seems to get reset somewhere between creating and posting.

Comment: @J... "*Here you're setting it to `utf-8` and observing that it changes **as expected***" - actually, it is a bug that it is being changed in this case, and that bug was already fixed last year.

Comment: @WolfgangBures Yes, and you haven't shown the code in between the initialization above and the area in the code where the problem manifests.  In this case you got lucky that Remy is familiar with the issue, but in general it's incredibly helpful if you can provide a coherent, self-contained piece of code that independently demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because:

- you are using an older release of Indy 10 <sup>1</sup>.
- you are setting the `ContentType` property *after* setting the `CharSet` property.
- you are not specifying a `charset` attribute value on the `ContentType` property.

So, in this case, the `ContentType` property setter is resetting the `CharSet` property with a default value, instead of preserving the current value.

<sup>1</sup> This was [already fixed](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/commit/0917fe1fc96b2be662be88fdc179d6fded284e55) back in July 2019:

> Patch for Embarcadero RSP-13703. Updating various ContentType property setters to preserve an existing CharSet property value if it is already set and a new charset attribute is not being specified.

You should update your installed copy of Indy with the latest code from Indy's [GitHub repo](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy) (or, at least, apply the same fix to your existing copy and then [recompile Indy](http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx)).

Otherwise, you can simply change your code to either:

- swap the order of the two property assignments:

```pascal
Socket.Request.ContentType:='text/txt';
Socket.Request.CharSet:='utf-8';
```

- specify a `charset` attribute value on the `ContentType` assignment, which will update the `CharSet` property accordingly:

```pascal
Socket.Request.ContentType:='text/txt;charset=utf-8';
```

Comment: if I would know how to download the latest code from GitHub - I just don't get it how to...

Comment: @WolfgangBures Well, now you have something new to learn.  There are surely plenty of answers here and tutorials showing you how to use Git.   This is something you'll use over and over again, so it's worth taking the time to figure it out.